# How does this lambda reverse the strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
class Solution:
    def reverseVowels(self, s: str) -> str:
        vowels = re.findall('(?i)[aeiou]', s)
        return re.sub('(?i)[aeiou]', lambda x:vowels.pop(), s)
```

I can't wrap my head around how this reverses the vowels. please explain.

Comment: It doesn't do it alone. The regex pattern finds all vowels. First, `.findall` then puts all vowels in the string in a list: `vowels`. Then, `re.sub`, which takes a callable to substitute. For each match in the string, it is replaced by whatever the callable returns. It's the same pattern, so it matches all vowels again. All the function does is return `vowels.pop()`, which will take the last element in the vowels list, so the first vowel found will be replaced by the last, and the second with the second to last, and so on and so forth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) uses the lambda as a replacement function, i.e. it matches each vowel in the string going forwards, and the lambda feeds in replacement strings going backwards. How that works is `list.pop()` removes the last item from the list and returns it. The last item in `vowels` is the last vowel in `s`. That continues to the second-last item, third-last, etc.

The parameter `x` is ignored.